# Alignment Error - css Border

Tags: css

[image]

Please view image; the all images have:

```
image{
    border-left, border-top, border-bottom: 2 solid gray;
}
```

And also `image:last-child` has:

```
image:last-child{
    border-right: 2 solid gray;
}
```

But it show a slip in bottom border.

Please help me for correct alignment.

Comment: I think, the size of last image is smaller than the rest of them.

Comment: I would be easier to help i you could create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`image {
border: 2px solid grey;
}`
and not have to write the `:last-child` property

Comment: the problem arise when is code like this so I go for :last-child

Answer (score 0):

All the images need to be the same height to keep the borders aligned